# How to set TTL to expire documents using MONK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, monk

I read the [MongoDB documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) in order to figure the how to expire a document using the Time To Live property.

The doc says:

> To expire data after a specified number of seconds has passed since
>   the indexed field, create a TTL index on a field that holds values of
>   BSON date type... For example, the following operation creates an
>   index on the log_events collection’s createdAt field and specifies the
>   expireAfterSeconds value of 3600 to set the expiration time to be one
>   hour after the time specified by createdAt

```
db.log_events.createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

> When adding documents to the log_events collection, set the createdAt
>   field to the current time:

```
db.log_events.insert( {
   "createdAt": new Date(),
   "logEvent": 2,
   "logMessage": "Success!"
} )
```

**How do I do that using node [Monk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monk)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be:

```
db.log_events.ensureIndex({ "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 })
```

Documentation on [ensureIndex](https://automattic.github.io/monk/docs/collection/ensureIndex.html)

> Ensures that indexes exist, if it does not it creates it